# Node.JS Express to HTML data transfer

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js

I am creating a login application with node.js, I seem to have ran into a knowledge deficit in the area of transferring strings from the server to html.

I posted my current code at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wsrjc0kr/).
My application verifies the credentials to the mysql table then generates a basic token that contains the username password and the ip address of the user.

In the last block of code, where the client html posts to the server, I have two segments where you see send to basic user page and send to admin page. 
I have attempted to research this subject, but i get nothing pertinent to the situation. can anyone guide me in the right direction on sending the user to the admin or user page while sending the token alongside of it?

As well, how can the express server send data to the client, for example
on the page, I want the database to hold pertinant information regarding the user, like address and phone number. How can this information be transmitted from the server to the client via html?

```
app.post('/', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {

var date = new Date();
con.query("SELECT * from users WHERE username=" + con.escape(req.body.username) + " AND password=" + con.escape(req.body.password), function (err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
        if (rows == '' && rows == '') {
            console.log('User Failed to login to the server with @'.red + con.escape(req.body.username) + ':' + con.escape(req.body.password));
            res.sendFile(__dirname + '/admin/failure.html');

        } else {
            var isadmin = rows[0].admin;
            var cryptomap = [req.body.username + ',' + req.body.password + ',' + ip];
            var strcryptomap = cryptomap.toString(); // convert array to string
            var token = encrypt(strcryptomap);
            console.log(token + ' SENT'.red);
            var backto = decrypt(token); //decr
            var arr = backto.toString().split(","); // SPLITTING STRING TO SATISFY /VERIFY *************************************************
            console.log(arr[0] + ' has valid token, encryption succsessful'.green);
            con.query('UPDATE users SET crypto=' + con.escape(token) + 'WHERE username=' + con.escape(req.body.username), function (err, rows, fields) {
                if (err) {

                    res.send(500);


                } else {

                    console.log('Updated Crypto for ' + req.body.username);
                    if (isadmin == 0) {
                        // send to basic user page 
                        res.send('USER');
                    } else {

                        //send to admin user page
                        res.sendto('http://google.com/?' + token);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }



   });
   });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start, I'll answer the actual question you are asking.

The way I normally handle what you are trying to accomplish, is by using an ajax POST from the front end with the users credentials(https of course, never send credentials using http), have the server authenticate the user, create the token and respond to the ajax post with the token.  From here, if the authentication was successful and the server responded with a token and whatever other information you wanted to get, you have a few options for storing it, I personally use cookies.  After the token is stored, let the front end handle the redirect.

Having said all of that, I would definitely read up on authentication principles and the different ways your system can be attacked. I see a couple of red flags dealing with pretty basic authentication ideas/strategies.

**Edit :** Here is an example AJAX post to a login API endpoint that responds with a token and saves the username and token to cookies.  Obviously your result data in the success function may be organized differently than mine but can be accessed in the same way.  You can send whatever data you would like back in this result object and redirect accordingly

```
var loginData = { 
  username : $('#loginUsername').val(), 
  password : $('#loginPassword').val() 
} 


$.ajax({ 
  type : "POST", 
  url : [your-endpoint-url],
  data : loginData , 
  success : function(result) { 
      setCookie('appUN', result.username); 
      setCookie('appTok', result.token); 
      location.href = '/dashboard'; 
  }, 
  error : function(result) { 
    location.href = '/login/Error'; 
  } 
});


function setCookie(cname, cvalue) { 
  var d = new Date(); 
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + 10800000); 
  var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString(); 
  var path = "path=/"; 
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires + ";" + path; 
}
```

To actually send the data back to the client from the server, in your API endpoint, you would do all of your logic to check the users credentials and if their credentials were valid, you could create a token and return something like

```
res.json({ 
  username: username, 
  token: token
});
```

and this JSON object will be available in the success function as shown above.

If the users credentials were invalid, you could return something like

```
res.status(400).json({Message : "The username or password is incorrect"});
```

and because of the 400 status, it will be caught by the error function of your AJAX request

Comment: Okay, do you have a link to start? my google search always turns up something related to posting FROM html not receiveing data. 

https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=receive+form+data+html+with+ajax

Comment: Are you asking for a good place to start for your initial question about passing your token/data to the client? or for token authentication strategies?

Comment: Passing token/data to the client

Comment: I will edit my original answer to include an example